# Remove app from production and use beta testing instead

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I accendently uploaded a APK to Production instead Beta. Now i have unpublished the app und uploaded an APK to closed Beta testing and republished the app, but the other APK is still in production with the old version code. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I made similar mistake before and then unpublished my app. Started again the publish process with different package name as Google remembers your app by the package definition. You won't be able to delete an unpublished app. That needs to be unique. When you create your app, don't upload the apk first, just prepare store listing. Once done,you will see all the production, beta, alpha under APK menu.Just do your app to beta testing.hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have unpublished the app it will not be available for users in play store to download (though you may see it developer console), so no issues. I don't think Google Play developer console will allow to completely remove the app.